# Determine which disk partitions are used by Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, recovery-partition, system-reserved-partition

After removing a quad-boot from my laptop and leaving only Windows 10, I'm left with 9 partitions between 2 disks.
I can identify the primary Windows 10 partition, the EFI, and OEM partitions. 
How can I tell, of the 3 remaining Recovery Partitions and ~18GB primary partition, which are being used by Windows 10?

Here are the allocated partition sizes (Windows 10, on C, is on Disk 1)

[image]

(there are two additional unallocated partitions, of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run Reagentc /info command to know its disk and partition number.

[image]